# How to prove that a set with elements less than its dimension will not be spanning?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know how to prove that having $(n+1)$ elements in a subset of a vector space with dimension $n$ will automatically make the set of vectors linearly dependent but I am struggling to prove why a $(n-1)$-element set will not be spanning.

Edit: n = dimension of vector space

Comment: What's $n$? (We may be able to guess what you mean, but you should make it clear in your question.)

Comment: by n i mean the dimension of the vector space

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be your vector space and assume $\dim V=n$, i.e. every basis of $V$ contains $n$ vectors.

Assume a set $S=\{s_1,\dots,s_{n-1}\}$ spans the vector space. Then, by the *basis extension theorem*, there is a basis among these $n-1$ vectors, i.e. there is a subset $B\subseteq S$ s.t. $B$ is a linearly independent spanning set. Obviously, as $B\subseteq S$, we have $|B|\leq |S|=n-1$, i.e. $|B|\leq n-1$.

Now, the dimension of the vector space was assumed to be $n$ and we have found a basis with $n-1$ vectors, forcing immediatly $\dim V=|B|\leq n-1$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

According to one definition of the dimension of a vector space the dimension is the least number of linearly independent vectors which can span the space. Therefore if the dimension is $n$ you can not have a set of $n-1$ vectors which span your space.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a linearly independent set of vectors $S$ spanning vector space $V$. Now take another set with the same elements except one. Let this be $v_1$ without loss of generality. Now by definition $v_1$ can't be written as a linear combination of the other vectors. This implies that the set of $n-1$ vectors does not span $V$.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are talking about elements in a vector space over field $\mathbb{F}$ of dimension $n$. You should be asking first

> What does it mean for a vector space to have dimension $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

The usual definition: the cardinality of a spanning linearly independent set has size $n$.

> Is this well-defined?

This is precisely your question. Suppose there exists a spanning linearly independent of size $n$. You have shown there cannot be a spanning linearly independent set of size $n+1$. Can there be one of $n-1$? This is the essence of [Steinitz exchange lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma).